# I need help with a SQL-query that results in an error

Tags: mysql

I get the following error when I try to delete a record in the user table that has an entry in the feedback table:

e.g. when a record in the feedback table has a reference to the user table

[image: Table]

> 1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint
>   fails (`kbs`.`feedback`, CONSTRAINT `fk_feedback_user1` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON
>   UPDATE NO ACTION)

The relationship between the two tables:

[image: Relationship]

I hope someone could help me into the right direction and that my question is clear enough. I've followed a database design course but forgot a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user you are trying to delete have rows in the feedback table. Given your foreign key definition:

```
CONSTRAINT fk_feedback_user1 
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) 
    REFERENCES user (user_id) 
        ON DELETE NO ACTION 
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

You need to first delete from the feedback table:

```
delete from feedback where user_id = ?;
delete from user where user_id = ?;
```

An alternative is to change the foreign key to:

```
CONSTRAINT fk_feedback_user1 
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) 
    REFERENCES user (user_id) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE 
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

Any rows in the feedback table for that user will then be deleted automatically when you delete a user

Comment: One more option: delete from both tables in one statement: `DELETE f, u FROM user AS u LEFT JOIN feedback AS f ON u.user_id = f.user_id WHERE u.user_id = ? ;`

Comment: Given the error message this is likely MySQL so yes, that should be possible.